# Como realizar un autoclick en JQuery

Tags: jquery, vistas, onclick

Estoy haciendo una funcionalidad con ROR y JQuery en la cual mediante el click en un button cambia la apariencia de la vista y guarda además guarda un atributo en la bd, el cual una vez consultado debería de hacer un autoclick dependiendo de ciertas condiciones, las cuales se que se están cumpliendo, mas sin embargo este autoclick no se realiza.

```
<script>

  check_mode_background();

  // Small chart
  $(function () {
    $('.min-chart#chart-sales').easyPieChart({
      barColor: "#FF5252",
      onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
        $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
      }
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $('#dark-mode').on('click', function (e) {
      alert('Entre Aqui');

      e.preventDefault();

      $('footer, .card').toggleClass('dark-card-admin');
      $('body, .navbar').toggleClass('white-skin navy-blue-skin');
      $(this).toggleClass('white text-dark btn-outline-black');
      $('body').toggleClass('dark-bg-admin');
      $('h6, .card, p, td, th, i, h4, input, label').not('#slide-out i, #slide-out a, .dropdown-item i, .dropdown-item').toggleClass('text-white');
      //$('li a,').not('#slide-out i, #slide-out a, .dropdown-item i, .dropdown-item').toggleClass('text-black');
      $('.btn-dash').toggleClass('black blue').toggleClass('lighten-3 darken-3');
      $('.gradient-card-header').toggleClass('white black lighten-4');
      $('.list-panel a').toggleClass('navy-blue-bg-a text-black').toggleClass('list-group-border');

      $('.card.shadow.mb-4.dark-card-admin').css('background-color','transparent');

      var color = $(this).css("background-color");
      console.log(color);
      $('.modalResetOrDelete').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('.active').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('.form-control').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoMensaje').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoAsunto').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoreceiversMM').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoMMAsunto').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoMMMensaje').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#success_p_modal').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );


      if (color == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"){
        //oscuro
        $('body').css('background-color', '#363947');
        $('.h3.mb-2.text-gray-800').css('color','white');
        $('.h3.mb-0.text-gray-800').css('color','white');
        $(".dataTables_info").css("color","white");
        update_mode_background('Oscuro')
      } else {

        //blanco
        $('body').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
        $('.h3.mb-2.text-gray-800').css('color','#212529');
        $('.h3.mb-0.text-gray-800').css('color','#212529');
        $(".dataTables_info").css("color","#212529");
        update_mode_background('Blanco')
      }



    });
  });      

  function update_mode_background(color){
    url = "<%= admin_update_mode_path %>";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",  
      //dataType: "json",
      //http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/send_email_representing/1,subject,message
      url: url,
      data: {mode: color},
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (data) {
        // check_mode_background();
        if (data.status == "Ok"){
          // check_mode_background();
        } else if(data.status == "NotOK"){
          // check_mode_background();              
        }         
      },
      error: function (data) {

        // console.log("Ha ocurrido un error: "+data);
        // alert("Ocurrió un Error");
        // $('#EmailModal').modal('hide');
        // check_mode_background();
      }
    });
  }


  function check_mode_background(){

    var mode;
    alert('Entre');

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "<%= admin_check_mode_path %>",
      success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            mode = element,mode;
        });
        console.log(mode);
        if (mode == 'Oscuro'){
          //Significa que el modo seleccionado es oscuro
          if ($('body').css("background-color") == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'){
            //Significa que el fondo actual es oscuro
            alert('Pondre esto en oscuro');
            $("#dark-mode").trigger( "click" );

          }

        } else {
          //Significa que el modo seleccinado es el blanco
          if ($('body').css("background-color") != 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'){
            //Significa que el modo actual es distinto de blanco
            alert('Pondre esto en blanco'); 
            $("#dark-mode").trigger( "click" );
          }
        }       
      },
      error: function (data) {
          console.log("Ha ocurrido un error: "+data);
      }
    });
  }

</script>
```

Como se puede observar hay un button cuyo id es 'dark-mode' el cual comprobando los parámetros en la función check_mode_background, debería de forma automática clickear y realizar la tareas estipuladas en el on click, escrito en el presente código, pero este no se ejecuta. Agradecería la ayuda e indicaciones.

Ah el button que realiza la acción es este.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-black btn-sm" id="dark-mode">Cambiar Modo</button>
```

No se si debería de cambiarlo a un ancla que sea del tipo button.

Comment: especifica lo que deseas hacer, la verdad tu pregunta no se entiende.

Comment: Deseo que en donde tengo
alert('Pondre esto en oscuro');
 $("#dark-mode").trigger( "click" );

se haga un click automático a dark_mode y haga lo que hace el codigo cuando se le hace click

Comment: Entonces solo has una funcion, y llama la funcion donde quieres "que se haga click"

Comment: Solucionado el problema. Adjunto respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Al final obtuve la solución, pero repensando y haciendo algunos cambios comparto código por si desean mejorarlo (Agradecería el aporte si lo hacen) o usarlo.

```
<script>

  check_mode_background();

  /*
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) ----> Va  a Oscuro
    rgb(255, 255, 255) -----> Va a Claro
    Modo Claro: Con this: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) Con body: rgb(255, 255, 255)
    Modo Oscuro: Con this: rgb(255, 255, 255) Con body: rgb(54, 57, 71)
  */

  $(function() {
    $('#dark-mode').on('click', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var color = $(this).css("background-color");  

      console.log(e);
      console.log(this);
      //alert('COn this: '+$(this).css("background-color")+' Con body: '+$('body').css("background-color"));

      if ($('body').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || $(this).css("background-color") == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') { //Significa que el modo es claro va a Oscuro

        $('footer, .card').toggleClass('dark-card-admin');
        $('body, .navbar').toggleClass('white-skin navy-blue-skin');
        $(this).toggleClass('white text-dark btn-outline-black');
        $('body').toggleClass('dark-bg-admin');
        $('h6, .card, p, td, th, i, h4, input, label').not('#slide-out i, #slide-out a, .dropdown-item i, .dropdown-item').toggleClass('text-white');
        //$('li a,').not('#slide-out i, #slide-out a, .dropdown-item i, .dropdown-item').toggleClass('text-black');
        $('.btn-dash').toggleClass('black blue').toggleClass('lighten-3 darken-3');
        $('.gradient-card-header').toggleClass('white black lighten-4');
        $('.list-panel a').toggleClass('navy-blue-bg-a text-black').toggleClass('list-group-border');

        $('.card.shadow.mb-4.dark-card-admin').css('background-color','transparent');


        $('.modalResetOrDelete').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
        $('.active').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
        $('.form-control').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
        $('#labelCorreoMensaje').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
        $('#labelCorreoAsunto').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
        $('#labelCorreoreceiversMM').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
        $('#labelCorreoMMAsunto').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
        $('#labelCorreoMMMensaje').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
        $('#success_p_modal').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );

        //El color de fondo es disntinto de blanco por lo tanto es oscuro
        $('body').css('background-color', '#363947');
        $('.h3.mb-2.text-gray-800').css('color','white');
        $('.h3.mb-0.text-gray-800').css('color','white');
        $(".dataTables_info").css("color","white");
        update_mode_background('Oscuro');       

      } else if ( $('body').css('background-color') == 'rgb(54, 57, 71)' || $(this).css("background-color") == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') { //Significa que el modo es Oscuro va a Claro

        $('footer, .card').toggleClass('dark-card-admin');
        $('body, .navbar').toggleClass('white-skin navy-blue-skin');
        $(this).toggleClass('white text-dark btn-outline-black');
        $('body').toggleClass('dark-bg-admin');
        $('h6, .card, p, td, th, i, h4, input, label').not('#slide-out i, #slide-out a, .dropdown-item i, .dropdown-item').toggleClass('text-white');
        //$('li a,').not('#slide-out i, #slide-out a, .dropdown-item i, .dropdown-item').toggleClass('text-black');
        $('.btn-dash').toggleClass('black blue').toggleClass('lighten-3 darken-3');
        $('.gradient-card-header').toggleClass('white black lighten-4');
        $('.list-panel a').toggleClass('navy-blue-bg-a text-black').toggleClass('list-group-border');

        $('.card.shadow.mb-4.dark-card-admin').css('background-color','transparent');


        //El color de fondo es blanco
        $('body').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
        $('.h3.mb-2.text-gray-800').css('color','#212529');
        $('.h3.mb-0.text-gray-800').css('color','#212529');
        $(".dataTables_info").css("color","#212529");
        update_mode_background('Blanco'); 
      }        
    });
  });      

  function update_mode_background(color){
    url = "<%= admin_update_mode_path %>";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",  
      //dataType: "json",
      //http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/send_email_representing/1,subject,message
      url: url,
      data: {mode: color},
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (data) {
        // check_mode_background();
        if (data.status == "Ok"){
          // check_mode_background();
          console.log('Cambiado el color a: '+color);
        } else if(data.status == "NotOK"){
          // check_mode_background();              
          console.log('Color no cambiado');
        }         
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log("Ha ocurrido un error: "+data);
        // alert("Ocurrió un Error");
        // $('#EmailModal').modal('hide');
        // check_mode_background();
      }
    });
  }

  function check_mode_background(){

    var mode;
    //alert('Entre');
    // var color = $('body').css("background-color");  
    // alert(color);

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "<%= admin_check_mode_path %>",
      success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            mode = element,mode;
        });
        console.log(mode);
        if (mode == 'Oscuro'){
          //Significa que el modo seleccionado es oscuro
          dark_mode(this);
        }       
      },
      error: function (data) {
          console.log("Ha ocurrido un error: "+data);
      }
    });
  }


  function dark_mode() {

      $('footer, .card').toggleClass('dark-card-admin');
      $('body, .navbar').toggleClass('white-skin navy-blue-skin');
      $(this).toggleClass('white text-dark btn-outline-black');
      $('body').toggleClass('dark-bg-admin');
      $('h6, .card, p, td, th, i, h4, input, label').not('#slide-out i, #slide-out a, .dropdown-item i, .dropdown-item').toggleClass('text-white');
      //$('li a,').not('#slide-out i, #slide-out a, .dropdown-item i, .dropdown-item').toggleClass('text-black');
      $('.btn-dash').toggleClass('black blue').toggleClass('lighten-3 darken-3');
      $('.gradient-card-header').toggleClass('white black lighten-4');
      $('.list-panel a').toggleClass('navy-blue-bg-a text-black').toggleClass('list-group-border');

      $('.card.shadow.mb-4.dark-card-admin').css('background-color','transparent');


      $('.modalResetOrDelete').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('.active').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('.form-control').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoMensaje').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoAsunto').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoreceiversMM').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoMMAsunto').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#labelCorreoMMMensaje').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );
      $('#success_p_modal').removeClass( "text-white" ).addClass( "text-dark" );

      //El color de fondo es disntinto de blanco por lo tanto es oscuro
      $('body').css('background-color', '#363947');
      $('.h3.mb-2.text-gray-800').css('color','white');
      $('.h3.mb-0.text-gray-800').css('color','white');
      $(".dataTables_info").css("text-color","white");
      //update_mode_background('Blanco'); 

      $('#dark-mode').removeClass("btn btn-outline-black btn-sm");    
      $('#dark-mode').addClass("btn btn-sm white text-dark");             
  }

</script>
```

Lo que hice fue realizar de forma mas sencilla y simplificada ya que solo manejo dos tipos de estilos y uno ya esta por defecto, por lo tanto al consultar el la bd si tengo el modo que deseo cambiar en mi atributo voy a una función que hace los cambios receptivos y ya. Si el botón al que quería hacer click (Que ya no lo hago) , se le da click luego este mediante AJAX cambia el valor en la bd y cambia el estilo en la pantalla y listo.